# What is the difference between Redis Enterprise cache and Open Source Cache

Tags: redis

Need to understand the difference between Redis Enterprise cache and Open Source Cache on the basis of features, scalability and availability.

Could not find much doc on the same topic on the same. As this will help to have a better understanding on the same.